# Delphi effective way to handle socket error

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I am working with Data snap model thus i **have a client exe and server exe**.
client exe needs the server exe to be up and running for getting data from database.
When the server process is killed, I try to open a form which requires a query to be executed as **server is not running i get a socket error #10053**.

What i am looking for is any test application or a code snippet to handle socket error #10053.

[image]

As this is not a bug raised due to my code i want to catch this exception and show a message to the user saying the server is closed.

**Just a note :** I searched for a solution in SO dint find any. 
I have madexcept in my exe to catch the exceptions and send the bug report via mail.
Any help would be really appreciated.

**Update:**
I even tried with `ApplicationEvents OnException` this is working with a single form. I have `try/except` block almost everywhere required but looking for an alternative. I have a timer checking for connection is active or not i want alternative for this thanks

Comment: Handle the exception using `try/except` in the usual way. Handle the exception at the point where you wish to show the message to the user, and, well, show the message.

Comment: @David Heffernan  i want to handle it apllication level rather then on a button click or change of form. I even tried with 
`ApplicationEvents OnException` this is working with a single form.
I have 'try/except' block almost everywhere required but looking for an alternative.
I have a timer checking for connection is active or not i want alternative for this thanks.

Comment: So handle it in your `OnException` event then. What is the problem with that? You absolutely should remove all those try/except blocks that you scattered around the code in desperation. Are you aware that the dialog that you observe is presented by the debugger? You won't see that dialog if you run without the debugger. Anyway, seems like you want us to tell you what code to write, but we can't see any of your code. That doesn't seem very symmetrical.

Comment: This is only showed when you are debugging your application

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  `OnException` event then works with one form, I want to handle it some what  **globally throughout the application**, `have a timer checking for connection is active` i would like see alternative for 
`1. ApplicationEvents OnException ` and `2. Check at Timer`

Comment: `OnException` is a event of the application. It is not tied to any one form. It's rather pointless to discuss details of your code without showing the code. I can guess that you have a `TApplicationEvents` object on a form's design surface. That's why you think it is tied to a form. But all that is doing is setting up a handler for `TApplication`, because Delphi doesn't support multi-cast events. Why don't you throw away the `TApplicationEvents` objects and assign to `Application.OnException` directly. Remember that you don't need to do all your coding through the Object Inspector.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan
Even if it does not show when i am on release mode , i want to show a message as i have already mentioned above.
By making this duplicate this does not answer my question please allow others to look into this issue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks i tried the above method `throw away the TApplicationEvents objects and assign to Application.OnException directly`
not working my side

Comment: `OnException` works fine here. We can only guess what is wrong with your code. If you don't want the question to be about the debug notification, then you need to stop asking about the debug notification.  How about you edit the question to include a [mcve]. Don't bother trying to include the indy part, just raise a fake exception, `raise Exception.Create(...)`. Show us your `OnException` that is not doing what you need and it should be easy to debug. Then we can reopen and help you.

Comment: In a previous comment you asked to "... let others look into this issue". I did and there's really nothing more to say in addition to @David s comments. He already adressed the most probable reason to lack of response on application level. Also, what is wrong using a timer to periodically check the connection?

Comment: @TomBrunberg  Yes David has given almost probable way to handle and when it comes to timer i am thinking of checking with windows event level.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for your support  "catch the exception globally which my upline(senior) wants" , i would try and suggest to convince my upline with timer which is working